# Intellij - mercurial slow

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial

have you experienced any performance problems with hg in Intellij Idea (I'm using 12+).

Examples:

-refreshing VCS takes more than 20min (even when clicked 2 times in a row, takes additional 800MB of RAM)

-diff tool opens about 5sec (e.g. when browsing incoming changes) - when I'm using git it opens in a blink of an eye.

I've tried using different VCS settings but nothing seems to help.

Comment: I'm experiencing noticeable lag with IntelliJ 13

Comment: +1, me too. This is frustrating

Comment: +1 from me as well (ver 13.0.3). Mercurial is pretty responsive from terminal, but refreshing history from IntelliJ takes so much time (easily over 15 mins for a repo of size 2GB).